# A simple counting loop class

Tags: c++, iterator

**EDIT**: Updated version available here: [A counting loop class v2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269950/a-counting-loop-class-v2)

Ranges (C++20) aren't quite ready, so until then, I needed a reliable counting loop class that ​works fairly well to replace the old-style `for` loops:

```cpp
for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i)
```

With a simple `foreach` loop:

```cpp
for (int i: loop (x, y))
```

As implemented, it is inclusive for start value and end value.

Algorithms are supported by having all the typedefs needed for a `contiguous_iterator`.

Here is the class:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
class loop
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        using value_type=std::remove_cv_t<T>;
        using difference_type=value_type;
        using pointer=T*;
        using reference=T&;
        using iterator_category=std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_concept=std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
        using self_type=iterator;
        iterator(T x) : curr{x} {}
        T operator*()
        {
            return curr;
        }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            curr++;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const
        {
            return curr == rhs.curr;
        }
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& rhs)
        {
            return curr-rhs.curr;
        }
    private:
        T curr;
    };
    loop(T x, T y) : front{x}, back{y} {}
    iterator begin()
    {
        return front;
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return back + 1;
    }
    private:
    T front;
    T back;
};
```

And some usage examples:

```
int foo(int x, int y)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (auto z : loop(x, y))
    {
        sum+=z;
    }
    return sum;
}

#include <algorithm>

int goo(int x, int y, int z)
{
    loop range(x,y);
    auto f=std::find(range.begin(), range.end(), z);
    if (f != range.end())
    {
        return *f;
    }
    return x-1;
}

int ggg()
{
    return goo(3, 37, 17);
}
```

Comment: What's "not ready" about the Ranges library?  It seems pretty workable to me.

Answer (score 1):

We currently accept non-numeric types such as other iterators - is that intended?

---

I'm not convinced this is a good choice when `T` is unsigned:

> ```
>     using difference_type=value_type;
> ```

We probably want to use `std::make_signed_t<value_type>`.  Or perhaps even `std::make_signed_t<std::common_type_t<int,value_type>>` so we don't have truncating conversion with smaller types (which get promoted to `int`).

---

Unless I'm mistaken, an iterator is required to support both preincrement and postincrement, so we need `operator++(int)` as well (this one returns a new iterator, of course).

---

Since the iterator type is actually also the const iterator, we can declare `begin()` and `end()` as `const`.

Consider also providing `front()` and `back()` - you'll want to re-name the private members (perhaps `first` and `last`?).

---

Possible enhancement: consider also supporting a `step` increment between values (default 1).

Comment: Thanks, been working on your suggestions and adding `step` -- also you can see the issue with ranges in clang there ("ranges aren't ready") its wrapped with an `#if 0` -- https://godbolt.org/z/Px3nfYqPx