# A counting loop class v2

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

Rewrite of [A simple counting loop class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269903/a-simple-counting-loop-class/269912#269912) based on feedback:

This version adds a step parameter and better iterator concept support.
Counting is always done in a signed integral, and only integers and floats are supported.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <ranges>
#include <bit>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <concepts>

namespace util {
// Getting the right diff_type
template<typename T>
struct helper;

template<std::integral T>
struct helper<T> {
    using diff_type=std::make_signed_t<std::common_type_t<int,T>>;
};

template <class T>
requires (std::is_same<float, typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::value)
struct helper<T> {
    using diff_type=int;
};

template<std::floating_point T>
requires (!std::is_same<float, typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::value)
struct helper<T> {
    using diff_type=long long;
};
}

template <typename T>
    // Only numerics really make sense
    requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
class loop {
public:
    using value_type=std::remove_const_t<T>;
    using difference_type=typename util::helper<value_type>::diff_type;
    class iterator; // forward refernce
    using sentinel = difference_type;

    class iterator {
    public:
        using pointer=T;
        using reference=T;
        using iterator_category=std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_concept=std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using self_type=iterator;

        // std::weakly_incrementable
        iterator()=default;
        iterator(const iterator& it) = default;
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it) = default;
        ~iterator()=default;
        iterator(value_type v, value_type s) : curr{0}, first_val{v}, step{s} {}

        // std::random_access_iterator
        constexpr value_type operator[](difference_type idx) const {
            return first_val+idx*step;
        }

        // std::input_or_output_iterator<I>
        constexpr value_type operator*() {
            return operator[](curr);
        }

        // std::indirectly_readable<I>
        friend value_type operator*(const iterator& rhs) { return rhs.operator*(); }

        // std::weakly_incrementable<I>
        constexpr iterator& operator++() { // pre
// std::cout << "before: " << curr; 
            curr++;
// std::cout << " after: " << curr;
// std::cout << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
        constexpr iterator operator++(int) { // post
            iterator tmp=*this;
            this->operator++();
            return tmp;
        }

        // std::bidirectional_iterator<I>
        constexpr iterator& operator--() { // pre
            curr--;
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr iterator operator--(int) { // post
            iterator tmp=*this;
            this->operator--();
            return tmp;
        }

        // std::forward_iterator<I>
        // In C++20, 'operator==' implies 'operator!='
        // This is the sentinel version:
        // sentinel_for<T>
        // Note this MUST be `const`
        constexpr bool operator==(const sentinel& rhs) const {
std::cout << "  Comparing sentinel: " << curr << " vs " << rhs << std::endl;
            return curr >= rhs;
        }

        constexpr bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const {
std::cout << "  Comparing reg equal : " << curr << " vs " << rhs.curr << std::endl;
            return curr == curr;
        }

        // std::random_access_iterator<I>
        // std::totally_ordered<I>
        std::weak_ordering operator<=>(const iterator& rhs) const {
            return curr <=> rhs.curr;
        }

        constexpr difference_type operator-(const iterator& rhs) const {
            return curr-rhs.curr;
        }

        // std::iter_difference<I> operators
        iterator& operator+=(difference_type diff) { curr += diff; return *this; }
        iterator& operator-=(difference_type diff) { curr -= diff; return *this; }
        iterator operator+(difference_type diff) const { iterator tmp=*this; return tmp+=diff; }
        iterator operator-(difference_type diff) const { iterator tmp=*this; return tmp-=diff;  }
        friend iterator operator+(difference_type diff, const iterator& rhs) {
            return rhs + diff;
        }
        friend iterator operator-(difference_type diff, const iterator& rhs) {
            return rhs - diff;
        }
        // std::contiguous_iterator<I>
        pointer operator->() const { return curr; }
        using element_type = T; // required for std::input_iterator
    private:
        difference_type curr;
        value_type first_val;
        value_type step;
    };    
    using const_iterator=iterator;

    // back_val is the main concept here
    // all counting, despite type or step values, is just from 0 to N
    // iterator::operator* does the mapping from this count to the value
    static inline difference_type constexpr back_val(T x, T y, T z) {
        auto dist=y-x;
        //auto rounding=z/T{2};
        auto rounding=z/(y+x); // calculate an epsilon
        auto slices=(dist+rounding)/z;
        return static_cast <difference_type> (1+std::floor(slices));
    }
    loop(T x, T y, T z=1) : it{x,z}
        ,last_val{back_val(x,y,z)} {
    }
    constexpr inline iterator begin() const {
        return it;
    }
    constexpr inline sentinel end() const {
        return last_val;
    }
    constexpr inline const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return begin();
    }
    constexpr inline const sentinel cend() const {
        return end();
    }
    constexpr inline T front() const{
        return *begin();
    }
    constexpr inline T back() const {
        return *(begin()+(last_val-1));
    }
    private:
    const iterator it; 
    const sentinel last_val;

    static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::indirectly_readable<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::input_iterator<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::incrementable<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::bidirectional_iterator<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<iterator>);
    static_assert(std::sized_sentinel_for<iterator, iterator>);
    static_assert(std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<iterator>,
                  std::remove_cvref_t<std::iter_reference_t<iterator>>>);
    static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<iterator>);
  // static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<std::iter_reference_t<iterator>>);
  // static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<iterator>);
};
```

Some example usage:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int tst(T x, T y, T z)
{
    T t=1;
std::cout << "LOOP BEGIN: "
    << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << std::endl;
    for (auto i : loop(x,y,z))
    {
std::cout << "LOOP: " << i << std::endl;
        t*=i;
    }
std::cout << std::endl << "LOOP DONE" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;

    return t;
}

int tst1(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return tst(x,y,z);
}

int tst1a(int x, int y)
{
    return tst1(x,y,2);
}

int tst1a(long double x, long double y)
{
    return tst(x,y,2.0L);
}

// this can be compiletime resolved to: 636231680
int tst1b()
{
    return tst1(10,100,7);
}

int main()
{
    tst(1,10,1);
    tst(91,100, 3);
    tst(92,100, 3);
    tst(93,100, 3);
    tst(1.8, 3.8, .1);
    tst(1,1,2);
    tst(2,1,1);
    tst(-10,-20,-1);
}
```

Comparisons to ranges and C style

```
// Simple inclusinve loop [from, to]
// Clang is still having issues here:
auto inline loop2(std::size_t from, std::size_t to) {
    //return std::views::iota(from) | std::views::take(to);
    return std::views::iota(from,to);
}// Simple inclusinve loop [from, to]

int tst2(int x, int y)
{
    int t=1;
    for (int i : loop2(x,y))
    {
        t*=i;
    }

    return t;
}

int tst3(int x, int y)
{
    int t=1;
    for (int i=x; i <=y ; ++i)
    {
        t*=i;
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Available here: https://godbolt.org/z/Px3nfYqPx

Comment: Mine (with writeup):  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245139/DIY-range is a count only (no built-in end) and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245954/DIY-range-the-very-versitile-range-view-iterator-p (simple iterator pair is _not_ limited to counting iterators).  You're mixing the two ideas and unnecessarily limiting your class to arithmetic types.

Comment: Very nice write-up, but I'm not sure how that would handle something like `loop(1.8, 3.8, .1)` . The reason this is more complicated than my first version is to support `step` and floating types. I do like the idea of empty(), bool() and !(), so thanks.

Comment: @Glenn_Teitelbaum Yes, that code is as simple as possible to work, and the second version shows what's needed to give metadata to std algorithms.  It would be easy to add a step value to the pure counter.  The thing is that `end`  iterators in STL test for equality and for reliability this should check for exceeding the limit.  But if it's typed as a `sentinel` instead, then the `!=` operation could actually mean "no longer in the bounds to cover" and comparing two iterators would still mean the actual comparison you stated.

Comment: (I'm still thinking of keeping a _pure_ counting iterator (with step), and a general purpose range based on a current/end pair that can be used with anything.

Answer (score 3):

## Incorrect pointer types

When the value type of a range is `T`, then the following member types look wrong:

```
using pointer=T;
using reference=T;
```

A range like this doesn't point to actual objects, so pointers don't make sense. Remove them, and also remove the `operator->()` function.

## Problems in `back_val()`

Suppose I use the following:

```
loop(-10, 10, 1);
```

Then in `back_val()` there will be a division by zero. For integer types, you should not need to calculate an epsilon value. For floating point types, you are almost guaranteed to do it wrong.

If you want to do rounding, I suggest you just do the naive division:

```
difference_type slices = (y - x) / z + 1;
```

And then look at how close this gets you to the desired end value:

```
auto diff = (x + z * slices) - y;
```

You can normalize the difference by dividing it by `z`. Note how we now only divide by `z`, which should always be non-zero anyway for the counting loop to make sense.

## `difference_type` is not large enough

Consider this:

```
#include <climits>

// Loop over all the integers
for (auto i: loop(INT_MIN, INT_MAX)) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

`T` is `int`, and `difference_type` is also deduced to be `int`. However, `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` is larger than can be stored in an `int`. You could make it `unsigned`, but since your counter includes the end value, `INT_MAX - INT_MIN + 1` is just one too many for an `unsigned int`. You could try to promote it to the next larger integer type, but of course you will reach a limit at some point.

## Naming things

Almost all variables have good names, except the arguments of the constructor. `x`, `y` and `z`? Is it first, last, step or first, step, last? Make sure the names of the public function arguments are clear and descriptive.